# Changing a Desktop Computer to Server Computer

Tags: windows, windows-server

I am new to this community. Sorry if I ask a silly question or in an inappropriate community.

In our lab at university, we have a powerful desktop computer that we wish more than one user to be able to use it at the same time. The characteristics are as follows.

```
Processor: 2.4GHz (2 processors) (16 cores)
RAM: 128 GB
System type: 64-bit Operating System
```

Now, Windows 7 has been installed on this computer. If we want multiple users to be able to access this computer simultaneously, we should probably install Windows Server on it. (Is there any other ways?) I have some questions about this:

1. Is a server computer simply a powerful desktop computer, or does it have different hardware components?
2. If a server is a powerful desktop computer, do you think that our computer with the above characteristics has the potential to become a server? (It is supposed to serve around 3-4 people at the same, running simulation tools like COMSOL.)
3. Our school gives us these Window Servers for free: Windows Server 2012 Datacenter, Essential, Standard, Storage Server and Foundation. Which edition do you think is suitable for us?

Comment: It is the operating system that makes the biggest difference, server Domain OS's allow simultaneous connections when computers are joined to the domain. You can use a basic desktop OS as a file server by creating file/folder shares but this can get messy when more than one user needs access to the share at the same time and are making changes to files. The more users you have joined to a domain server the better server hardware you will need. I would go with standard.

Comment: You could set it up with Vmware Esxi and run Multiple Desktops off of it. Its how i have a similar Workstation setup in my home lab.

Comment: @user3276054 If you can have all of those editions for free, go with Datacenter. It is the most featured edition, and if it's free, there is no reason not too. Any computer (not just desktops) can also be made servers, although that it is not generally recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal desktop computers can be made servers. But generally servers have larger RAMs, HDDs, etc so that it can work fast and respond to requests soon enough.

Number of people a server can serve is dependent on the kind of operations users will be doing on the server instance.

You may read about the various types of Win servers and use as per your use case : [Win Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012)